# Loop for every key?

Tags: c#, xna

I have this code:

```
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.F11))
{
    if (rndKey == 11)
    {
        rightButton();
    }
    else
    {
    wrongButton();
    }
pressed = true;
}
```

Now the problem is: I need this for every key. Can I somehow loop this for everything with Keys.Blabla? I'm a newbie to C# and XNA so... Yeah.

Comment: I doubt you want a loop in this case. It's possible (within limits, since `Keys` is a "flags" enum, but there should be a much better way. Except I don't really get what you want to do.

Comment: What do you want to do? Looping through all the keys is probably not what you want as @Joey said.

Comment: I want to do this if for every Key.

Comment: @Bobgle - it would help if you explain WHY you want to do this if for every key, what is rndKey, etc.

Comment: rndKey = Randomkey. One random int I generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like:

```
foreach (Keys k in Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).GetPressedKeys()) {   
    switch (k) {
        case Keys.F11:
            if (rndKey == 11) { rightbutton(); } else { wrongbutton(); }
            break;
        case Keys.F12:
            if (rndKey == 12) { rightbutton(); } else { wrongbutton(); }
            break;
        default:
            wrongbutton();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's completely what I want. For what is the default:? Is that, what's gonna happen if anything else then these two Keys is pressed?

Comment: Yes. Default is if you have nothing to match in the Switch statement. ie: if the user presses F10, the default would be called. You might simply need to delete the 'wrongbutton();' part of default if you want nothing to happen.  But default is required to be in the switch.

Comment: Isn't that what I was asking? Anyway: thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Misread :)  Best of luck in your journey through XNA!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer will loop through all the weird keys, if you just want the function keys maybe something like:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
{
     string key = "F" + i.toString();
     Key k = Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), key);

     if(ks.isKeyDown(k))
     {
         if (rndKey == i)
         {
               rightButton();
         }
         else
         {
               wrongButton();
         }
     }
}
```

Not got a compiler so may need some tweaking.

Comment: This looks good, but I created a randomnumber and if the number matches the Key (its pretty random what number which key is) it uses rightButton(), if not wrongButton(). TL;DR: It's not working and I can't figure out what's the problem

Comment: The problem is not so much TL;DR but too short, doesn't explain ;) What does your random number correspond to, I get 11 to F11 so I assumed it was just function keys, but if not, what key does, say, 24 map to?

Comment: Wait to you mean the underlying integer value of the key? In which case, use Sam's answer, casting key to an interger and comparing:
if((int)key == rndKey) {rightButton();}...

Comment: @Bobgle if that's the case, then I'd look into event driven input rather than state-driven input.  I'm sure you can find a way online to wire up an event to detect whenever there's a keypress.

Comment: It's pretty random how I do that. 24 would be Tab. I'm just counting the keys on my keyboard to figure that out.

Comment: I have no idea how you could automate that if you have arbitrarily assigned numbers to keys. I guess your best bet is to make your own enum which is a subset of Keys with numbers corresponding to the numbers in Keys and then write some map between those numbers and your numbering system.

Answer (score 0):

this should be enough for what you want.
no loop or anything else needed, since you get generate a random key anyway:

```
ArrayList keys  = new ArrayList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)));
Keys randomKey = (Keys)keys[new Random().Next(keys.Count)];

if (ks.IsKeyDown(randomKey))
{
    rightButton();
}
else { wrongButton(); }
```